# When sending a text message to a phone with PHP, how can I control the sender name?

Tags: php, email, mobile, sms

My script looks like this:

```
<?php    
mail('xxxxxxxxxx@msg.telus.com', '', 'Message', 'From: John Doe \r\n', '-fxxxxxxxxxx@email.com');
?>
```

When I test the script by sending it to my phone, it receives the message fine, but it says the message is from "9999999999". My questions:

1. What does 9999999999 mean? The best I can glean from Google is that it indicates a private number/spam.
2. Is there a way to make the sender show up as "Jon Doe"? Essentially, I need to be able to use the PHP script to control the sender name that shows on the message when it's received by the phone.

I'm using an Android phone (Galaxy S3) to test, but this needs to be able to work on all phones and all service providers. Any solutions?

**UPDATE**

After some testing, here's what I found:

- With Fred's solution, no message is sent at all.
- If I get rid of the name in the header argument in Fred's solution, and get rid of the brackets around the email, I get the same result as before (it sends with 9999999999 in the sender field).
- If, after implementing the change above, I change the email from an address that does exist (I've been using my email so far) to an address doesn't exist, I get the same 9999999999 result.
- If I change the email to something that's not in email format (for example, just John Doe and not john@doe.com), it doesn't send at all.

All of this is the case for both my phone and my mom's phone (different model - not a smartphone - but with same service provider, and with her phone it's 6245 instead of 9999999999). With this in mind, and since Fred's solution worked for him but not me, I can only conclude it depends on the provider. Also, in my provider's case, they must use a regex to make sure the header's formatted as an email, regardless of whether the email server actually exists. I think I'll have to look into the mail() function more.

Comment: Do you not have a form used in conjunction with your mailer?

Comment: Like an HTML form? I do (I left it out here for simplicity), but I still don't know what to put into the mail() function to accomplish what I'm looking for.

Comment: Try my answer below, tested and working with the person's name coming up in the "from" email. Your original code had the `\r\n` show up in the subject line for some reason. You're going to need far more than that, in regards to `headers` in order to avoid being it taken for spam.

Comment: I'll need to look at your form code in order to know what your `POST` fields are.

Comment: this question is 2 years old. If you've found your solution since, or have given up on it, it should be deleted. someone downvoted my answer with no reason.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here, try this out for size:

```
<?php    
mail('xxxxxxxxxx@msg.telus.com', '', 'Message', "From: John Doe <xxxxxxxxxx@email.com>\r\n");
?>
```

**Added options:**

For example, if your form contains something to the affect of:

```
<label for='name'>Enter Name: </label>
<input type="text" name="name">

<label for='email'>Enter Email Address:</label>
<input type="text" name="email">

<textarea rows="2" name="message" cols="20"></textarea>
```

Then you could use something like this:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

mail("xxxxxxxxxx@msg.telus.com", "Subject here", "$message", "From: $name <$email>\r\n");
echo "Message sent.";

?>
```

I'm assuming, of course.

Comment: Fred: Thanks for the answer. See my edit on the original question. I actually deleted my form and am using the exact code I quoted in the question, so it can't be a form issue.